# std::shared_ptr operator [] equivalent access

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

In C++17 `std::shared_ptr` has an `operator []` to allow indexing vector-based pointers (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_at)

How do I obtain similar accessing if such operator is not available and I still want to use a smart pointer for an array of elements such as:

```
std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> data;
data.reset(new unsigned char[10]>;
// use data[3];
```

Comment: AFAIK pre C++17 you cannot have an array type in a `shared_ptr`.  Right now you would have the wrong deleter which leads to UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver surely OP can, with a correct deleter? (which OP didn't provide).

Comment: @user2079303 Good point.  I forgot about passing a custom deleter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
data.get()[3]
```

However, keep in mind what Nathan said in comments. The default deleter of `std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>` is wrong for a pointer allocated by `new[]`. You will need to use `std::shared_ptr::reset(Y* ptr, Deleter d);` with an appropriate deleter:

```
data.reset(new unsigned char[10], [](auto p){ delete[] p; });
```

Or, if you don't like the ugliness of the lambda, you can define a reusable helper:

```
struct array_deleter {
    template<typename T> void operator()(const T* p) { 
        delete[] p; 
    }
};

// ...

data.reset(new unsigned char[10], array_deleter());
```

Comment: Thanks! So, that means I should use `data.reset(new unsigned char[10], delete[] )` ?

Comment: @rkioji that's not syntactically correct. See the edit for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `shared_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10>>` instead.

Or `shared_ptr<std::basic_string<unsigned char>>` if you need dynamically selected size.

With modern C++, there isn't a good reason to use new, delete or naked arrays. If you need them for compatibility, there is always .data().

Comment: Could you include how the OP would use `operator[]` with that?

Comment: std::shared_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10>> a; return (*a)[5];